# RDD word phrases count error Py4JJavaError

Tags: python, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql, rdd

I want to perform word count of a given text file where the data is loaded as RDD.
The data is gotten from [Zindi](https://zindi.africa/competitions/swahili-news-classification/data)

```
text_rdd = SparkSession.builder.appName("intro").master("local[*]").getOrCreate()
sc = text_rdd.sparkContext.textFile('Data/sw_short_articles.txt')

#applying mapreduce function
rdd_phrase_cnt = sc.filter(lambda x: (x.split()))\
.filter (lambda x : filter_rows(x))\
.map(lambda x: (x.split("\t")[2]))\
.map(tokenize_into_ngrams_phrase)\
.flatMap (lambda x: x.split(","))\
.map(lambda x : (x,1))\
.reduceByKey (lambda x,y: x+y)
```

After running the above lines of codes, I am getting an error which says Py4JJavaError.
error output:

```
Py4JJavaError: An error occurred while calling z:org.apache.spark.api.python.PythonRDD.collectAndServe.
: org.apache.spark.SparkException: Job aborted due to stage failure: Task 0 in stage 2.0 failed 1 times, most recent failure: Lost task 0.0 in stage 2.0 (TID 2) (4a07c02f2966 executor driver): org.apache.spark.api.python.PythonException: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/pyspark/python/lib/pyspark.zip/pyspark/worker.py", line 686, in main
    process()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/pyspark/python/lib/pyspark.zip/pyspark/worker.py", line 676, in process
    out_iter = func(split_index, iterator)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/pyspark/rdd.py", line 3472, in pipeline_func
    return func(split, prev_func(split, iterator))
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/pyspark/rdd.py", line 3472, in pipeline_func
    return func(split, prev_func(split, iterator))
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/pyspark/rdd.py", line 540, in func
    return f(iterator)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/pyspark/rdd.py", line 2554, in combineLocally
    merger.mergeValues(iterator)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/pyspark/python/lib/pyspark.zip/pyspark/shuffle.py", line 253, in mergeValues
    for k, v in iterator:
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/pyspark/python/lib/pyspark.zip/pyspark/util.py", line 81, in wrapper
    return f(*args, **kwargs)
  File "<ipython-input-63-37ccdff29a85>", line 27, in <lambda>
IndexError: list index out of range
```

Please I need explaination why this error and any supporting ideas or codes to solve the above problem.

Comment: it is not downloadable without login, could you post the sample or else upload it?

Comment: Why do you need to use RDD API for your processing? Can you describe data processing logic you need? It's much simpler to use `spark.read.csv` to load CSV files